# How can I make PIR motion sensor faster?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, motion-detection

I'm working with a raspberry pi and two PIR motion sensors, HC-SR501 specifically.

I'm trying to cut down the time delay on each sensor - the amount of time before motion can detected again, but I can't seem to do better than ~5 seconds, which is way too long for my purposes.

I've found conflicting info about these sensors too - some places say they have adjustable time delays ranging for ~4 sec - (http://www.mpja.com/download/31227sc.pdf)
and others saying .5 - 200 sec: (http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=pir+motion+sensor)

Which is it? If I'm truly limited hardware wise by ~5 seconds, is there some other way to get around that time delay? Are there faster PIR motion sensors out there?

EDIT: As requested below, I'm using Python to program the devices on my Raspberry PI. I currently attach an event_detect to the PIR pin and make a callback. Perhaps there's a better way, maybe with polling to reduce delay times?

Comment: There are 2 potentiometer on it: http://stak.com/image/data/products/235/235914/hc-sr501-labelled-alt.png did you try to regulate them?

Comment: I'm struggling to see what this question actually has to do with Python.

Comment: Sorry, should've have mentioned I'm writing my program in Python on the pi. Was wondering if there's some software subtlety involving Python to reduce delay times.

Comment: @AndreaDeGaetano, I did try to adjust the delay potentionmeters to their min value. That only cut it down to ~5 seconds. One of the links I posted above has the min delay at ~.3 seconds, which is way better than what I'm able to get.

Comment: Damn, I have exactly the same issue with my sensor and adurino.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the issue but regular feature. You are using HC-SR501 sensor which is intended to put signal on for 5s-300s. It has PIR sensor, but also a logic to process input signal from PIR and to treat it for the typical purpose of turnight the light on. For this purpose it is normal that after detection light will be on for 5-300s.

Since your case is totaly different, you cannot use this sensor without modification. It is not problem with your program but the way sensor logic works.

At the moment I got the same problem - how to modify sensor to lower the time to some 1 sec or so.

Also after this 5 seconds there is additional problem that next 3 seconds are intentionlly in "no motion efect" mode, meaning that any motion in this period is ignored!

Comment: I've had this same issue - Searching the net tonight trying to see if there's an easy documented way to just remove the delay all together from the cheap HC-SR501's.

I tried a HC-SR505 - that was even worse - hardwired 8 second delay.

One work around I found that worked for me was the parallax 555-28027 sensor, which is pretty close to instant on/off.

Still searching for an HC501 schematic, I suspect desoldering one of the smt resistors would lower the min delay to zero.

Comment: found this video on shorting a few resisters to get the time down on an HC-SR501 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juOtoUabyH8